# How to set the number of cosmoDB item processed in micro-batch in Spark Structured streaming?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, mlflow

Basically, I'm using spark structured streaming to read sensor data (24 sensors with frequency 1s) from cosmo, doing some manip and calling a MLFlow classification model.

Thus, I need a batch of 24 input items (or a modulo of 24).

My code look like this so far :

```
  "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint" : cosmosEndpoint,
  "spark.cosmos.accountKey" : cosmosMasterKey,
  "spark.cosmos.database" : cosmosDatabaseName,
  "spark.cosmos.container" : cosmosContainerName,
  "spark.cosmos.upsert" : "true"
}

# Configure Catalog Api to be used
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog", "com.azure.cosmos.spark.CosmosCatalog")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog.spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint", cosmosEndpoint)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog.spark.cosmos.accountKey", cosmosMasterKey)

# Initiate Cosmos Connection Config Object
changeFeedCfg = {
  "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint": cosmosEndpoint,
  "spark.cosmos.accountKey": cosmosMasterKey,
  "spark.cosmos.database": cosmosDatabaseName,
  "spark.cosmos.container": cosmosContainerName,
  "spark.cosmos.read.partitioning.strategy": "Default",
  "spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled" : "false",
  "spark.cosmos.changeFeed.startFrom" : "Now",
  "spark.cosmos.changeFeed.mode" : "Incremental",
  "spark.cosmos.changeFeed.ItemCountPerTriggerHint" : 24,
}

# Load model as a PysparkUDF
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf(spark, model_uri='runs:/*********/model', result_type='double')
literal_eval_udf = udf(ast.literal_eval, MapType(StringType(), StringType()))

fixedStream = spark.readStream.format("cosmos.oltp.changeFeed").options(**changeFeedCfg).load()

fixedStream = fixedStream.select('_rawBody').withColumn('temp', regexp_replace('_rawBody', ',"_rid".*', '}')).drop('_rawBody')
fixedStream = fixedStream.withColumn("temp", map_values(literal_eval_udf(col("temp"))))
keys = ['datetime', 'machine', 'id', 'factor', 'value', 'Sensor']
for k in range(len(keys)):
    fixedStream = fixedStream.withColumn(keys[k], fixedStream.temp[k])
fixedStream = fixedStream.select('factor','machine','Sensor','value')

def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    df = df.groupBy('factor','machine').pivot("Sensor").agg(first("value"))
    columns = list(df)
    df = df.withColumn('predictions', loaded_model(*columns)).collect()
    df.write.option("mergeSchema","true").format("delta").option("header", "true").mode("append").saveAsTable("poc_industry.test_stream")
    
fixedStream.writeStream.foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()
```

I have tried using with the read stream:

- ItemCountPerTriggerHint,
- limit
- maxItemCount

I also tried slowing down the write with the trigger(processingTime='x seconds') option.

It runs without error, But none of it seems to have an effect on the batchDF size, indeed numInputRows seems to be varying randomly between (3 and 100).

As anyone achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by **@Christopher Tao** in [Stream Your Cosmos DB Changes to Databricks with Spark 3](https://towardsdatascience.com/stream-your-cosmos-db-changes-to-databricks-with-spark-3-8044b237b853)

Use **`maxItemCountPerTriggerHint`** instead of **`ItemCountPerTriggerHint`** to only handle a **certain number of objects** per trigger.

***Code Example:-***

```py
"spark.cosmos.changeFeed.maxItemCountPerTriggerHint" : "24"
```

Comment: Hi @PratikLad-MT, Thanks a bunch for the tip, but this doesn't seems to work for me : it raises : `IllegalArgumentException: The config property 'spark.cosmos.changefeed.maxitemcountpertriggerhint' is invalid. No config setting with this name exists.`

Comment: it isn't listed as a possible parameter here : https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3_2-12/docs/configuration-reference.md...

Comment: try spark.cosmos.read.maxItemCount